# OpenCV Image Filter Ordering

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to use multiple filter together in the code but the order of cv2.filter2D and cv2.medianBlur produces different output. Can some help me out with the reason?

The commented-out code gives a more blurry image.

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('xyz.jpg')

ksize1 = 5
sigma = 3
ksize2 = 10

gkern = cv2.getGaussianKernel(ksize1, sigma)
fimg = cv2.filter2D(img, -1, gkern)
fimg = cv2.medianBlur(fimg, ksize2)

#fimg = cv2.medianBlur(img, ksize2)
#gkern = cv2.getGaussianKernel(ksize1, sigma)
#fimg = cv2.filter2D(fimg, -1, gkern)

cv2.imwrite('xyz_new.jpg',fimg)
```

Comment: That is to be expected since the two filters are not linear and do not commute. So order is important and you will get different results from the two orderings.

Comment: @fmw42 Can you suggest me some sources where I can learn more about linear and non-linear filter ordering of images?

Comment: `@inteldefense` Not off-hand. But search Google for "linear and nonlinear filters in image processing" and I think you will find many references. Wikipedia is also a good source.

Comment: My first statement was not worded well. The convolution is linear. But the median is not. See convolution properties at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution. Two convolutions should be commutative. But not two medians or a median and a convolution.